# How to add image to product object in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I write a custom module to create product, import product. Everything is fine but I have a problem with link to product image. When I check the link to product image in source view, when I see the front of the shop the link is:

```
http://example.com/30-home_default/Array.jpg
```

There is an array in the URL because prestashop get in from:

```
$product->link_rewrite = $link_rewrite;
```

And the $link_rewrite has two index (two language). How to resolved this problem ?

```
public function createProductsObject($productID, $productName, $price, $weight, $category, $description, $link_rewrite, $singleStock, $getCategoryID, $getImages, $attrs) {
        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = $productName;
        $product->ean13 = '';
        $product->reference = '';
        $product->id_category_default = $getCategoryID;
        $product->category = $getCategoryID;
        $product->indexed = 1;
        $product->description = $description;
        $product->condition = 'new';
        $product->redirect_type = '404';
        $product->visibility = 'both';
        $product->id_supplier = 1;
        $product->link_rewrite = $link_rewrite;
        $product->quantity = $singleStock;
        $product->price = round($price - (18.69 / 100) * $price, 2);
        $product->active = 1;
        $product->psoft_hurtobergamo_id = $productID;
        $product->add();


        $product->addToCategories($getCategoryID);

        $shops = 1;
        $count = 0;


        foreach ($getImages->children() AS $image) {
            $url = $image->attributes()->url->__toString();

            $id_product = $product->id;
            $image = new Image();
            $image->id_product = $id_product;
            $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($id_product) + 1;

            if ($count == 0) {
                $image->cover = true;
                $count = 1;
            } else {
                $image->cover = false;
            }

            if (($image->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
                    ($image->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true && $image->add()) {
                if (Configuration::get('PSOFT_HURTO_BERGAMO_THUMB') == '0') {
                    $productThumb = false;
                } else {
                    $productThumb = true;
                }
                $image->associateTo($shops);
                if (!self::copyImg($id_product, $image->id, $url, 'products', $productThumb)) {
                    $image->delete();
                }
            }
        }



    protected static function copyImg($id_entity, $id_image = null, $url, $entity = 'products', $regenerate = false) {
        $tmpfile = tempnam(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_, 'ps_import');
        $watermark_types = explode(',', Configuration::get('WATERMARK_TYPES'));

        switch ($entity) {
            default:
            case 'products':
                $image_obj = new Image($id_image);
                $path = $image_obj->getPathForCreation();
                break;
        }

        $url = urldecode(trim($url));
        $parced_url = parse_url($url);

        if (isset($parced_url['path'])) {
            $uri = ltrim($parced_url['path'], '/');
            $parts = explode('/', $uri);
            foreach ($parts as &$part) {
                $part = rawurlencode($part);
            }
            unset($part);
            $parced_url['path'] = '/' . implode('/', $parts);
        }

        if (isset($parced_url['query'])) {
            $query_parts = array();
            parse_str($parced_url['query'], $query_parts);
            $parced_url['query'] = http_build_query($query_parts);
        }

        if (!function_exists('http_build_url')) {
            require_once(_PS_TOOL_DIR_ . 'http_build_url/http_build_url.php');
        }

        $url = http_build_url('', $parced_url);

        $orig_tmpfile = $tmpfile;

        if (Tools::copy($url, $tmpfile)) {
// Evaluate the memory required to resize the image: if it's too much, you can't resize it.
            if (!ImageManager::checkImageMemoryLimit($tmpfile)) {
                @unlink($tmpfile);
                return false;
            }

            $tgt_width = $tgt_height = 0;
            $src_width = $src_height = 0;
            $error = 0;
            ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '.jpg', null, null, 'jpg', false, $error, $tgt_width, $tgt_height, 5, $src_width, $src_height);
            $images_types = ImageType::getImagesTypes($entity, true);

            if ($regenerate) {
                $previous_path = null;
                $path_infos = array();
                $path_infos[] = array($tgt_width, $tgt_height, $path . '.jpg');
                foreach ($images_types as $image_type) {
                    $tmpfile = self::get_best_path($image_type['width'], $image_type['height'], $path_infos);

                    if (ImageManager::resize($tmpfile, $path . '-' . stripslashes($image_type['name']) . '.jpg', $image_type['width'], $image_type['height'], 'jpg', false, $error, $tgt_width, $tgt_height, 5, $src_width, $src_height)) {
// the last image should not be added in the candidate list if it's bigger than the original image
                        if ($tgt_width <= $src_width && $tgt_height <= $src_height) {
                            $path_infos[] = array($tgt_width, $tgt_height, $path . '-' . stripslashes($image_type['name']) . '.jpg');
                        }
                        if ($entity == 'products') {
                            if (is_file(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '.jpg')) {
                                unlink(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '.jpg');
                            }
                            if (is_file(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '_' . (int) Context::getContext()->shop->id . '.jpg')) {
                                unlink(_PS_TMP_IMG_DIR_ . 'product_mini_' . (int) $id_entity . '_' . (int) Context::getContext()->shop->id . '.jpg');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (in_array($image_type['id_image_type'], $watermark_types)) {
                        Hook::exec('actionWatermark', array('id_image' => $id_image, 'id_product' => $id_entity));
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            @unlink($orig_tmpfile);
            return false;
        }
        unlink($orig_tmpfile);
        return true;
    }

    protected static function get_best_path($tgt_width, $tgt_height, $path_infos) {
        $path_infos = array_reverse($path_infos);
        $path = '';
        foreach ($path_infos as $path_info) {
            list($width, $height, $path) = $path_info;
            if ($width >= $tgt_width && $height >= $tgt_height) {
                return $path;
            }
        }
        return $path;
    }
```

I use a debug in Netbeans but I cant find how to resolved the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Getting images from product

```
<?php
//after you saved a product and you have the id (eg. product id: 1) for language 1
$p = new Product(1,false,1);
$productImages = $p->getImages(1);
```

See the full [`getImages()` Product class method](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Product.php#L3050)

### Setting images for product

```
<?php
//we need to create a new image ObjectModel
$image = new Image();
$image->id_product = 1; //associate
$image->add(false);
```

Please take a closer look to the [`Image` class](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/classes/Image.php#L38)

### Talking about ovverrides

You can achieve this by placing an [override of `Product` class](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/#overriding-a-class).

Since you're in a module you have to place an `override` folder inside your module folder.

Example if module is named `mymodule`:

In `modules/mymodule/override/classes` place a `Product.php` class like this:

```
<?php

class Product extends ProductCore{

}
```

**Note that** those overrides are enabled on module install and removed on module uninstall.